# Android - Как пользоваться MediaMetadataEditor?

Tags: android, java, android-mediaplayer

Пожалуйста, помогите найти какой-нибудь материал по сабжу или приведите пример кода, где редактируются мета-данные mp3 трека. Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Пока только есть [Первоисточник](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataEditor.html)

Comment: Можете почитать [тех.документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataEditor.html)